# Unexpected behaviour when concatenating Bags from file read

Tags: python, dask

I am new to Dask and come from Apache Spark platform.
I am trying to replicate a routine in Dask where I load JSON files by day and select some fields to be included for downstream computation.
What I discovered is that the for loop is not unrolled thus only the last append is effective (in my case this is the last day of the file data). I believe I need some form of copy operator during the append operation to generate a copy of that dataframe but I cannot find any information from the documents.
The workaround for me currently is to compute a pandas dataframe and append it which is okay but would like to know if there is a better approach.

```
import dask
import json
import os

os.makedirs('demodata', exist_ok=True)              # Create data/ directory

b = dask.datasets.make_people()                 # Make records of people
b.map(json.dumps).to_textfiles('demodata/*.json')   # Encode as JSON, write to disk

dict_filter = lambda x, y: dict([ (i,x[i]) for i in x if i in set(y) ])

bags = []

for in_path in glob.glob('demodata/*.json'):
    
    in_path = Path(in_path)

    file_str = in_path.stem
    print('Loading file %s' % file_str)
    json_bag = db.read_text(in_path).map(json.loads)
    filtered_bag = json_bag.map(lambda evt: dict_filter(evt, ['age','name']))
    file_dict ={'filename':file_str}
    file_bag = filtered_bag.map(lambda d: {**d,**file_dict} )
    
    bags.append(file_bag)
    
all_bags = db.concat(bags)
all_people = all_bags.to_dataframe().compute()

assert all_people.filename.nunique() == 10
```

Comment: It would be convenient if you could remove parts of that that are not related (gz, filter, update) and give example data and expected output. One thing I do spot: `update` does not return anything.

Comment: Ehy sure will simplify the example give me a day.

Comment: @mdurant please see updated example, maybe is the dictionary creation?

Answer (score 1):

I think we might be able to solve this without a loop, by using [`dask.bag.read_text(..., include_path=True)`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/bag-api.html#dask.bag.read_text) keyword argument.

```py
import dask.bag as db
import json
import os

# Ran this once, then no more
# import dask
# os.makedirs("demodata", exist_ok=True)  # Create data/ directory
# b = dask.datasets.make_people()  # Make records of people
# b.map(json.dumps).to_textfiles("demodata/*.json")  # Encode as JSON, write to disk

get_keys = lambda d, keys: {key: d[key] for key in d if key in keys}

df = (
    db.read_text("demodata/*.json", include_path=True)
    .map(lambda x: {**json.loads(x[0]), **dict(filename=os.path.basename(x[1]))})
    .map(lambda evt: get_keys(evt, ["age", "name", "filename"]))
    .to_dataframe()
    .compute()
)

print(df)

assert df.filename.nunique() == 10
```

Prints out

```
     age                 name filename
0     50    [Chieko, Daniels]   0.json
1     52       [Irina, Tyson]   0.json
2     63      [Ali, O'connor]   0.json
3     47   [Doretta, Wiggins]   0.json
4     22   [Gregorio, Barnes]   0.json
..   ...                  ...      ...
995   49        [Lory, Combs]   9.json
996   43      [Nicky, Mullen]   9.json
997   57  [Carolyne, Mendoza]   9.json
998   58     [Arthur, Monroe]   9.json
999   40        [Shin, Nunez]   9.json
```

Does this answer your question? Or were you looking for something slightly different?

Comment: Hi there,
yes that is helpful but I would like to understand why with the for loop the DAG is unable to correctly combine multiple bags? There will be cases where I still have to use a for loop, for example when there are gzipped json files. I just want to understand more behind the scenes.